# R visNetwork updateSelectizeInput when nodes are deselected using visEvents

Tags: r, shiny, visnetwork

I have written code (using shiny) that creates an absolutePanel consisting of a number of selectizeInputs as well as a network of nodes (visNetwork). When an option is selected from one of the drop down lists, particular nodes are highlighted. Currently, if you click on the canvas and deselect the nodes, the drop down list resets (using updateSelectizeInput). However, if you repeat this process, the drop down lists don't reset. Why are the drop down lists only resetting on the first click? I have included some of my code below.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$network_proxy_select <- renderVisNetwork({
      visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%
      visNodes(font = list(face = "arial,sans-serif")) %>%
      visOptions(highlightNearest = list(enabled = TRUE, degree = 0)) %>%
      visInteraction(navigationButtons = FALSE, keyboard = TRUE) %>%
      visPhysics(stabilization = FALSE) %>%
      visEvents(type="on", click = "function(properties){
                Shiny.onInputChange('click', properties.nodes);
              ;}")
    })

    observe({
      if(is.null(input$click)) { 
        updateSelectizeInput(session, "sel1", selected="")
        updateSelectizeInput(session, "sel2", selected="")
        updateSelectizeInput(session, "sel3", selected="")
        updateSelectizeInput(session, "sel4", selected="")
        updateSelectizeInput(session, "sel5", selected="")
        updateSelectizeInput(session, "sel6", selected="")
      }
    })

    ...
}

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
      absolutePanel(top=20, left=20, height="auto", width="auto", draggable=FALSE,
        selectizeInput(inputId = "sel1", selected="", choices = c("", ...), multiple = FALSE, width="500px"),
        selectizeInput(inputId = "sel2", selected="", choices = c("", ...), multiple = FALSE, width="500px"),
        selectizeInput(inputId = "sel3", selected="", choices = c("", ...), multiple = FALSE, width="500px"),
        selectizeInput(inputId = "sel4", selected="", choices = c("", ...), multiple = FALSE, width="500px"),
        selectizeInput(inputId = "sel5", selected="", choices = c("", ...), multiple = FALSE, width="500px"),
        selectizeInput(inputId = "sel6", selected="", choices = c("", ...), multiple = FALSE, width="500px")
      ),
      mainPanel(visNetworkOutput("network_proxy_select", height="900px"), width="auto")
    )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```